Why for the electromagnetic force we need "Maxwell's Stress Tensor" to be a tensor to find flux through a surface?
If we are computing the flux of a fluid through a surface, then we can simply integrate the dot product of the fluid flow through the normal component of an element of surface area... No tensor is required.
But when we are computing the electromagnetic force on a surface we look at the first term in the equation:

Where a tensor is required. I'm thinking that for a fluid flux we only need to take the component of the fluid that travels parallel to the surface element, and I guess for the E&M force it makes sense we would need more indices because we have a lot more going on... but still I just feel like one of the genius's who regulars this site could give me some insight into why what's happening physically requires the mathematical apparatus of tensors. I feel like we could just as easily break down a fluid flux into x-y-z components acting on x-y-z surface elements.
PS I understand tensors real good.
Also side quest: In griffiths derivation of the formula above, he introduces a term $(\triangledown \cdot \vec{B})\vec{B}$ (which equals zero because magnetic monopoles do not exist $\triangledown \cdot \vec{B}=0$) at one point so that the equation has some nice symmetry. Does the addition of this null term manifest itself in anyway when utilizing Maxwell's stress tensor?

to find flux through a surface First you have to ask yourself “flux of what?” before you can understand why you need a tensor. What is flowing across the surface is electromagnetic momentum (and energy).

Okay, but why does this make a difference? Why do we need to use tensors for the flux of electromagnetic momentum whilst a vector suffices for say, fluid flux.

Fluid flux is how much fluid flows across. This is a scalar. Electromagnetic flux is how much energy-momentum flows across. This is a 4-vector.

Right. and i'm asking somebody to explain why this is so. $T_{ij}$ is the energy-momentum in the i'th direction is exerted on an element of area oriented in the j'th direction, and then we take the scalar product of this with elements of area oriented in some direction... Seems a bit redundant.
